# Quadratic equation solver using ABC and PQ formula

Tags: beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, rust

Getting my feet wet with Rust, I implemented a solver for quadratic equations.
I implemented both, ABC and PQ formula solvers, to challenge myself with branch conditions.

`main.rs`

```rust
mod quadratic;
use quadratic::QuadraticEquation;

fn main() {
    let equation1 = QuadraticEquation::new(3.0, 3.0, -18.0);
    let equation2 = QuadraticEquation::new(1.0, 3.0, -18.0);
    let equation3 = QuadraticEquation::new(-4.0, -5.0, 12.0);
    let equation4 = QuadraticEquation::new(1.0, 0.0, 50.0);
    let equation5 = QuadraticEquation::new(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    println!("The solutions of {} are {}", equation1, equation1.solve());
    println!("The solutions of {} are {}", equation2, equation2.solve());
    println!("The solutions of {} are {}", equation3, equation3.solve());
    println!("The solutions of {} are {}", equation4, equation4.solve());
    println!("The solutions of {} are {}", equation5, equation5.solve());
}
```

`quadratic.rs`

```rust
use std::fmt;

mod solution;
pub use self::solution::Solution;

mod functions;
use self::functions::with_sign;

pub struct QuadraticEquation {
    a: f64,
    b: f64,
    c: f64,
}

impl QuadraticEquation {
    pub fn new(a: f64, b: f64, c: f64) -> QuadraticEquation {
        QuadraticEquation { a: a, b: b, c: c }
    }

    pub fn solve_abc(&self) -> Solution {
        let root = f64::sqrt(f64::powi(self.b, 2) - 4.0 * self.a * self.c);
        let x1 = (-self.b + root) / (2f64 * self.a);
        let x2 = (-self.b - root) / (2f64 * self.a);
        Solution::new(x1, x2)
    }

    pub fn solve_pq(&self) -> Solution {
        if self.a != 1.0 {
            return Solution::none();
        }

        let minus_b_half = -self.b / 2.0;
        let root = f64::sqrt(f64::powi(self.b / 2.0, 2) - self.c);
        let x1 = minus_b_half + root;
        let x2 = minus_b_half - root;
        Solution::new(x1, x2)
    }

    pub fn solve(&self) -> Solution {
        if self.a == 1.0 {
            println!("a = 1 -> Using pq-formula.");
            self.solve_pq()
        } else {
            self.solve_abc()
        }
    }

    pub fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        let mut result = Vec::new();

        if self.a != 0.0 {
            result.push(format!("{}x²", with_sign(self.a, true, result.is_empty())));
        }

        if self.b != 0.0 {
            result.push(format!("{}x", with_sign(self.b, true, result.is_empty())));
        }

        if self.c != 0.0 {
            result.push(with_sign(self.c, false, result.is_empty()));
        }

        result.join(" ")
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for QuadraticEquation {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.to_string())
    }
}
```

`quadratic/solution.rs`

```rust
use std::fmt;

pub struct Solution {
    pub x1: f64,
    pub x2: f64,
}

impl Solution {
    pub fn new(x1: f64, x2: f64) -> Solution {
        Solution { x1: x1, x2: x2 }
    }

    pub fn none() -> Solution {
        Solution::new(f64::NAN, f64::NAN)
    }

    pub fn error(&self) -> bool {
        self.x1.is_nan() && self.x2.is_nan()
    }

    pub fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        if self.error() {
            "N/A".to_string()
        } else {
            format!("x₁ = {}, x₂ = {}", self.x1, self.x2)
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Solution {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.to_string())
    }
}
```

`quadratic/functions.rs`

```rust
pub fn with_sign(number: f64, omit_one: bool, first: bool) -> String {
    if number < 0.0 {
        with_minus(abs_str(number, omit_one), first)
    } else {
        with_plus(abs_str(number, omit_one), first)
    }
}

fn abs_str(number: f64, omit_one: bool) -> String {
    if omit_one {
        empty_if_one(number.abs())
    } else {
        number.abs().to_string()
    }
}

fn with_minus(number: String, first: bool) -> String {
    if first {
        format!("-{}", number)
    } else {
        format!("- {}", number)
    }
}

fn with_plus(number: String, first: bool) -> String {
    if first {
        number
    } else {
        format!("+ {}", number)
    }
}

fn empty_if_one(number: f64) -> String {
    if number == 1.0 {
        "".to_string()
    } else {
        number.to_string()
    }
}
```

How can I improve the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, the special case of a=1 is not very interesting. You could as well remove the branch and just use abc everytime.

Instead you could check if a is close to 0 and choose a [different formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/866331/63696) that is more numerically stable in this case.

Second I dislike the flag arguments a little:

```
with_sign(number: f64, omit_one: bool, first: bool)
```

They make the call site cryptic, I can hardly see why the arguments are passed that way. I would replace this with 2 separate functions: One for the sign/operator and one for the coefficient:

```
    if self.a != 0.0 {
        let withSpace = result.any(); // Not sure if this works in Rust
        result.push(format_sign(self.a, withSpace))
        result.push(format!("{}x²", format_coefficient(self.a)));
    }
//...
    if self.c != 0.0 {
        let withSpace = result.any(); // Not sure if this works in Rust
        result.push(format_sign(self.a, withSpace))
        result.push(format_constant(self.c));
    }
```

So format_sign would print a + or - and with or without the space and then format_constant will just print the number and format_coefficient can return "" if the number is exactly one.

Sorry, I don't have a rust compiler at hand.